# Ubuntu 20.04 No Bluethooth Found

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, system-settings

I have PC with wifi/bluethooth card. The wifi works fine. The bluetooth was fine but today it does not work on my ubuntu and restarting does not work. On the ubuntu `20.04` setting GUI, it displays:

```
No Bluetooth Found
Plugin a dongle to use Bluetooth
```

while I believe there is no hardware issue. Mostly I suspect the ubuntu settings center.

[image: Ubuntu bluetooth not found]

Efforts:

```
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
sudo rmmod btusb
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
sudo systemctl start bluetooth
```

.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
Restarting bluetooth (via systemctl): bluetooth.service.
```

.

```
sudo hcitool dev
Devices:
```

.

```
systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-03-30 07:57:33 AEDT; 13s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 47046 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18980)
     Memory: 508.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─47046 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Mar 30 07:57:33 mypc systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Mar 30 07:57:33 mypc bluetoothd[47046]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
Mar 30 07:57:33 mypc systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Mar 30 07:57:33 mypc bluetoothd[47046]: Starting SDP server
Mar 30 07:57:33 mypc bluetoothd[47046]: Bluetooth management interface 1.20 initialized
```

.

```
sudo apt install unity-control-center
(not sure what to do with it, no much options there)
```

.

```
sudo bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# 
(no idea what to do here)
```

Info:

```
uname -a
Linux mypc 5.13.0-37-generic #42~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 15 15:44:28 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

.

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

.

Comment: There are lots of similar question, but none of the solutions work for me.

Comment: Look at a kernel message for missing firmware: `sudo journalctl -b -k | grep firmware` and post the output of `lspci -k` (maybe you have to install the tool with `sudo apt update && sudo apt install pcitutils`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually fixed the problem by a turning off the PC waiting for 30 seconds and starting again.

A warm restart alone after the update did not fix the problem.

I write this in case it helps anyone else.

Comment: Is it a dual boot with Windows?

Comment: @Pilot6, no, I only have Ubuntu on my PC. I do not have any dual boot.

Comment: Thank you so much @ar2015 the cold restart did the trick for me also.

Comment: It is really helpful after tried others' solution. Thank you.