# Ubuntu 20.04 Bluetooth dongle not recognized

Tags: 20.04, usb, bluetooth, dongle

I just bought a Sony Bluetooth headset and connected the dongle to my Ubuntu 20.04 machine. The dongle is seen on `lsusb`:

```
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 174c:5316 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASMT1153e
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 054c:0e53 Sony Corp. INZONE H9 / INZONE H7
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1b1c:1b3a Corsair Corsair Gaming K70 RAPIDFIRE Keyboard 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Fourth line from bottom : `Sony Corp. INZONE H9 / INZONE H7`

I also did the steps described in most guides :

```
$ sudo modprobe btusb
$ sudo rmmod btusb
$ rfkill unblock bluetooth
$ sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
$ sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
```

As a result, the service is on and appears ok:

```
$ systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-12-29 14:22:15 IST; 5s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 6432 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 77017)
     Memory: 2.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─6432 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Dec 29 14:22:14 Onan01 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Dec 29 14:22:15 Onan01 bluetoothd[6432]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
Dec 29 14:22:15 Onan01 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Dec 29 14:22:15 Onan01 bluetoothd[6432]: Starting SDP server
Dec 29 14:22:15 Onan01 bluetoothd[6432]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
```

However, I still don't see my Bluetooth dongle either on the settings GUI nor on `bluetoothctl`:

```
$ bluetoothctl list
$ bluetoothctl power on
No default controller available
```

One weird thing I noticed is that while one guide ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399904/ubuntu-20-04-no-bluethooth-found)) says a cold restart is required, every time I restart (cold or warm), I have to redo the following steps:

```
$ sudo modprobe btusb
$ sudo rmmod btusb
$ rfkill unblock bluetooth
$ sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
$ sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
```

Apparently, none of these setting changes seem to stick. After a restart, the bluetooth service is off and the `btusb` module is not loaded.

On dmesg, I saw the following, which could be the beginning of an explanation?

```
$ dmesg | grep bt
[   98.978225] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[  101.889983] usbcore: deregistering interface driver btusb
```

Why the F*** is the `btusb` module being "deregistered" at startup? No idea. I am at a loss here. Any help would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by "The dongle is seen on lsusb"? If it is `Sony Corp. INZONE H9 / INZONE H7`, it is not a BT device at all. It is a proprietary wireless dongle.

Comment: @Pilot6 Oh, I see. But what can it be if it is not Bluetooth?

Comment: I wrote what it is in the previous comment.

Comment: @Pilot6 You mean that there are proprietary dongles which do not use Bluetooth to communicate with devices? But if it is not Bluetooth, what is it?

Comment: There is a lot of proprietary dongles, e.g Logitech mouse, etc. They use some proprietary protocols.

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth module doesn't work, because you don't have a Bluetooth device.

```
Sony Corp. INZONE H9 / INZONE H7
```

is not a Bluetooth device.